# how to stop streamlit to reexecute the code

Tags: streamlit

there have some code i want execute one times. this is my code:

```
import streamlit as st

# 构建聊天界面
st.set_page_config(page_title="Title")
st.title("ChatUI")
if text := st.chat_input(placeholder="Say something."):
    print(text)
    st.chat_message("user").write(text)
print("repeat...")
```

the `print("repeat...")` is the code i don't want repeat execute.but when i start the streamlit, it's print that:

```
repeat...
repeat...
repeat...
```

when i chat in the ui, and input `hello`, it's print that:

```
repeat...
repeat...
repeat...
hello
repeat...
```

where should i put the `print("repeat...")` to avoid it repeat.

stop repeat print repeat...

Answer (score 0):

Not reproduceable

```
    ...
      For better performance, install the Watchdog module:

  $ xcode-select --install
  $ pip install watchdog

repeat...
bllab
repeat...
balblalba
repeat...
it is not repeated
repeat...
```